# Why is my team no allowed to manage iCloud container?

Tags: ios, containers, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-drive

I created a new project and gave it iCloud capabilities with CloudKit checked. When I try to access the container from CloudKit dashboard, I get a message saying:

> There was a problem listing the record types
>
> Team ... not allowed to manage container iCloud.us.gnolaum.MakeYourOwnStickers

I have tried to unset and then reset settings from Xcode and from Apple developer website, but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permissions on your CloudKit container and make sure the right users have right access.

Once you sign in to the [CloudKit Dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/), check the permissions here:

[image]

[image]

It should list the users on your developer team as defined on https://developer.apple.com/account.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried that, but I got the same message. Somehow the problem corrected itself. I don't know how.

Comment: I created a new Gmail address for testing purposes only, and invited this address to join my team. I see the new account in the "Developer" part of the Users page on appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users. But when I try to add this new user on the container permission, I only see me (my main account). Can free developer account added to a team access a CloudKit dashboard? I really need this to test my app and see records in the private database (log the new user on the Simulator and a device to test sync is working, etc.).